# Posso utilizar o resultado da cláusula Case como um campo no Select?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Está pergunta faz referência a esta:
[Como retornar dia da semana e hora formatada sql server 2008?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105890/como-retornar-dia-da-semana-e-hora-formatada-sql-server-2008)
Estou tentando resolver isso:

```html
SELECT 
 CASE DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'DOMINGO'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'SEGUNDA'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'TERCA'
     WHEN 4 THEN 'QUARTA'
     WHEN 5 THEN 'QUINTA' 
     WHEN 6 THEN 'SEXTA'
     WHEN 7 THEN 'SABADO'
  END DIASEMANA,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(05),GETDATE(),108) AS 'HORA',
* FROM TB_ESTRACAO
where DIASEMANA = 'S'
```

Comment: Esse método pode até dar certo (mas cuidado com o retorno desse `datepart` DW pq pode variar dependendo de config.) mas lugar de formatar data é no front end. Na visualização do usuário mesmo por questões de manutenção e localização/globalização

Comment: Pode sim, não há restrição de uso neste caso :)

Comment: @MarllonNasser, você entendeu a pergunta? Estou usando o resultado do case como um campo na tabela "where DIASEMANA = 'S' ", isso não da certo.

Comment: mas nunca que `DIASEMANA` vai ser = 'S'. Você pode filtrar direto do `DATEPART`. `where DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 6`

Comment: @MarllonNasser, na pergunta eu estou fazendo referência a outra pergunta, onde eu tenho uma tabela TB_ESTRACAO onde em uma coluna com o nome do dia da semana, por isso eu pensei em usar desta forma.

Comment: A questão já foi resolvida, postei a minha solução na outra pergunta que tem um link nesta.

Comment: você duplicou a pegunta e respondeu a própria pergunta. :|